# How Can I get log in time while using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, security

I am using spring security 3 and would like to display the time when user logged in to current session.

Does Spring security provide any such token?

Thanks,
- Akshay

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable option would be customizing your [Spring Security filter chain](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) to save a timestamp in the user's session when a successful login occurs. Then you would access it in the same way you access any session attribute.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you can [add your own filters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters) to the Spring Security filter chain. 
You could add a filter after `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, if you are using `http/form-login`, or after `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, in case of `http/http-basic`, so we guarantee that the session is already created. 
To cover both, you can add a filter after the last one, and add the information to the session.

**Declare your filter-bean:**

```
<bean id="myFilter" class="com.MyFilter"/>
```

**Add it to the chain, right after `BasicAuthenticationFilter`:**

```
<http>
    <custom-filter ref="myFilter"  after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    ...
```

**Your `doFilter` method should look like:**

```
private static final String LOGGED_TIME_KEY = "LOGGED_TIME";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null && session.getAttribute(LOGGED_TIME_KEY) == null) {
            session.setAttribute(LOGGED_TIME_KEY, new Date());
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Keep in mind that you can use other hooks. You can add it even to your *AuthenticationProvider*.

**EDIT:**

There is a easier way to do that, if you are using `form-login`. 
You can use a custom [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html). To define it, update your `form-login` tag, adding the attribute `authentication-success-handler-ref`.