# Spring security: change locale on login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to change the locale based on currently logged in user. The handler works fine, I18n too but I can't understand how can I pass the `LocaleResolver` into the handler?

```
<http use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/wellcome/" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="false"
            authentication-failure-url="/wellcome/?error=1" username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <remember-me key="butler_crm" token-validity-seconds="-1" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/logout"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/wellcome/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated"/>
        <custom-filter ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>
    </http>
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.ejl.butler.spring.AuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

The handler:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    /*@Autowired
    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;*/

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        UserDetailsExtended user = (UserDetailsExtended) authentication.getPrincipal();

        /*localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale(user.getCommunicationLanguage()));*/
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer for an complete example:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531649/change-locale-on-login

Comment: @Ralph the problem that if I use that code I get the `No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver] found for dependency` exception

Comment: I rember, I solved the problem once by using an event handler for the login event. When using events then the event handler bean can be configered in the spring web context, so the local resolver is available.

Comment: @Ralph and do you have an example? What do you mean by configured?

Comment: Example: one answer has a complete example,   configured: the spring bean configuration `<bean id= class= .../>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than making a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` set the locale, why not implement an custom `LocaleResolver` that resolves the locale from the UserDetails object (using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to get the authentication object)?